# axios strips off some bits of URL path

Tags: javascript, axios

I am inspecting a code(which is written by someone else) that makes simple GET and POST requests to the server using axios.

Everything seems to be working fine, except that a single request to the server.

When making the following request,

```
url = 'api/items';

axios.get(url).then(res => {
  // do some work
});
```

Some bits of URL path get stripped off for some reason.

The above request is supposed to be sent to

```
https://test.com/aaa/bbb/api/items
```

instead of

```
https://test.com/api/items
```

All other requests work fine(i.e. `https://test.com/aaa/bbb/api/xxx`), but not this one.

What could be the possible cause of this?

Comment: Do the code set baseURL? Is the sample page who perform `get` had different URLs?

Comment: Are the other apis called the same?

Comment: @Zesky The base URL does not seem to be set

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal Yes, all other apis are called in the same way

Comment: You aren't setting the base url in other api calls? I mean, they all work like this?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal No, others work fine without setting it for some reason. A difference between this and others is it is invoked in a modal window by the user click

Comment: modal window and the other is perform at same page with same url?

Comment: @Zesky yes, basically there is an index page(index.scala.html) loading in the modal(modal.scala.html) like `<div>@modal()</div>` within the index page. Both are written in Twir

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com/';
```

then u can use

```
url = 'api/items';

axios.get(url).then(res => {
  // do some work
});
```

and send a request to `https://api.example.com/api/items`

You may like to check Global [Axios Config Defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults) to get more information

As it mentioned in the documentation, You can have several instances and set default configs for each instance like this:

```
// Set config defaults when creating the instance
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
});

// Alter defaults after instance has been created
instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
```

Comment: yes, I am aware of this, but I want to know why all apis work fine except one

Comment: @d-_-b it may initialize each axios instance in each template, instead of initializing an axios instance to use in all templates

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the API path was set to `/api/items`, not `api/items`.

That leading `/` was causing the problem.